# Nominatim installation error: Out of memory for node cache dense index

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis, nominatim

I am installing Nominatim on my Ubuntu server 14.04 through this [link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) and trying to load OSM data into my postgreSQL database. For loading into my database I am using this command as given in the link:

```
~/Nominatim/utils/setup.php   --osm-file data/latest.osm.pbf   --all --osm2pgsql-cache 1024 2>&1   | tee setup.log
```

But it is throwing an error

```
Using projection SRS 4326 (Latlong)
NOTICE:  table "place" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "keyvalue" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "wordscore" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "stringlanguagetype" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "keyvaluetype" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  function get_connected_ways(pg_catalog.int4[]) does not exist,  skipping
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Out of memory for node cache dense index, try using "--cache-strategy  sparse" instead
Error occurred, cleaning up
ERROR: Error executing external command: /home/nominatim/Nominatim /osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 256 -P 5432 -d nominatim /home/nominatim/data/latest.osm.pbf
Error executing external command: /home/nominatim/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 256 -P 5432 -d nominatim /home/nominatim/data/latest.osm.pbf
```

My ubuntu has 7GB of RAM and I am not sure why this error is coming. I ran the above command by reducing the cache size to 512 and then 256 but it is running into same error. I am not sure how to use `--cache-strategy  sparse` in the given command.

Screenshot of my Error:
[image]

Could anybody help with the setup?

Comment: Cross post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/44750/nominatim-installation-error-out-of-memory-for-node-cache-dense-index

Comment: @mmd Could you help me with my issue?

Comment: The error message above recommends to try `--cache-strategy sparse` to overcome the error message. Did you already do that?

Comment: I don't know how to configure setup.php file for `--cache-strategy sparse`. Could you help me with this because I have tried all other methods as far.

Comment: Okay I fixed `--cache-strategy sparse` and used this command 

     ~/Nom1/Nominatim/utils/setup.php   --osm-file data/latest.osm.pbf   --all --osm2pgsql--cache-strategy sparse --osm2pgsql-cache 1024
                                                                                                                  but sadly same error :|

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue.

Go through this link and follow all the instructions posted there.

[Problem Resolved](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/issues/306)

Comment: Can you explain how you fixed --cache-strategy sparse?